# How do I change the sound file for my windows form application using combo box?

Tags: winforms

I am developing a Windows Form Application. Currently I am working on the Settings aspect for my windows form app. On the settings form, I would be able to toggle the alert tone for my application. The default sound code is as follows

```
public String defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\applause-2.wav";
```

As for the settings, I have included 2 default tones for the user to select through a combo box. The code for the combo box are as follows,

```
private void comboBoxSound_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxSound.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ReportStatus("Alert tone changed to 'Beep(1)'!");
            backgroundFormObject.getSetting().defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\beep-1.wav";
        }
        else
        {

            ReportStatus("Alert tone changed to 'Beep(2)'!");
            backgroundFormObject.getSetting().defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\beep-2.wav";
        }

        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        Stream stream = File.Open(appPath + "\\setting.sd", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();


        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, backgroundFormObject.getSetting());
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Why is it that whenever I select another tone, and I play the sound, the effect is still the same as the original alert tone which is applause. Do I have to wait for the file to load finish before I play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to solve it myself using the following code

```
private void comboBoxSound_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxSound.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ReportStatus("Alert tone changed to 'Beep(1)'!");
            settingObject.defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\beep-1.wav";
        }
        else
        {

            ReportStatus("Alert tone changed to 'Beep(2)'!");
            settingObject.defaultAlertTone = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Sounds\\beep-2.wav";
        }

        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        Stream stream = File.Open(appPath + "\\setting.sd", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();


        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, settingObject);
        stream.Close();
    }
```